# Wso2 APIManager 1.10.0 Analytics

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I'm using Wso2 APIManager 1.10.0  and enabled analytics. Im running distributed docker containers for API Manager and DAS 3.0.1 in another container. When I try to access statistics in Publisher. What could be the problem?

```
[2016-08-16 19:29:37,127] ERROR - APIUsageStatisticsRestClientImpl Error occurred while Connecting to DAS REST API
[2016-08-16 19:29:37,129] ERROR - usage:jag org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.client.exception.APIMgtUsageQueryServiceClientException: Error occurred while Connecting to DAS REST API
```

Comment: Can you check whether you can connect DAS from APIM docker node?

Comment: I have the similar issue: publisher does not show the stats using RDBMS config. What is your final solution to share?

Comment: @J D, there could be multiple reason to AM dashboard not showing stat like Configuration issues and Network issues. So that, you can check stat  data are collected by the DAS correctly and summary stat are saving in the RDBMS or DAS summary table.
Then finally you can test whether data in the summary tables, is getting into the stat dashboards.